# Tracking Highs in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to create a script to display a history of the highest high as it goes through the base series.

Currently this works OK apart from it hops as it goes back in time. I would like to drop the tf by 1 when the ta.highest returns null, but it won't let me run ta.highest in a for loop so that I can subtract one each time it returns null.

Is there a way of gradually lowering the timeframe when ta.hightest returns null?

```
//@version=5
indicator("HighsTracker", "", true)
tf = input(title="LongestTime", defval="700")
htfHigh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1D", high, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

float HH = 0

H7 = ta.highest(htfHigh, tf )[1]
H6 = ta.highest(htfHigh, tf - 100)[1]
H5 = ta.highest(htfHigh, tf - 200)[1]
H4 = ta.highest(htfHigh, tf - 300 )[1]
H3 = ta.highest(htfHigh, tf - 400 )[1]
H2 = ta.highest(htfHigh, tf - 500 )[1]
H1 = ta.highest(htfHigh, tf - 600 )[1]

if HH < H7
    HH := H7
else if HH < H6
    HH := H6
else if HH < H5
    HH := H5
else if HH < H4
    HH := H4
else if HH < H3
    HH := H3
else if HH < H2
    HH := H2
else if HH < H1
    HH := H1

plot(HH, color = color.green, linewidth = 5)
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgX6C.png)

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out for anybody who needs it.

```
tf = 3000
float highestHigh = 0
iter = 1

for i = 1 to tf 
    if htfHigh[iter] > highestHigh
        highestHigh := htfHigh[iter]
    iter := iter + 1
    
plot(highestHigh, color = color.blue, linewidth = 5)
```